# Windows Within An App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

My C# WPF application has multiple windows, which may be open at once.  One of these windows is for Notifications, and must remain Topmost (or like), until it is acknowledged.  The problem I am having is that when I set `Topmost=true;` the window will display on top, but later windows must be closed before the buttons on the Notification window can be clicked.

I have tried, `BringIntoView();`,`Activate();`, `Focus();`,and Calling `Show();` again.

All of these fail, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the other windows invoked modally? E.g. with `window.ShowDialog()`? Doing so will trump any "topmost" settings of non-modal windows.

Comment: THANKS, Pete!!  That's it, you saved sooo much time.